# Console Application "Pausing" in AWS EC2

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2, console-application

I have a C# Console Application that is basically a crawler running multithreaded requests and saving results into a database running on a EBS backed instance on EC2.

Last night, I started the application from the Powershell command line and left it running. By saying that I left I mean I closed the RDP session without logging off.

Today when I came back for it the console hasn't updated since the time I logged out from my EC2 instance yesterday and seemed to be frozen.

I typed one key in the keyboard and then it simply "resumed" from where it left off as you can see from the outpout of the Log4Net (both to console and text file) below:

```
2013-07-18 20:45:17,854 [30] DEBUG J3 - Reply for Request <959> -> <721>
2013-07-18 20:45:17,870 [11] DEBUG J3 - Reply for Request <441> -> <1433>
2013-07-19 18:17:35,466 [1] DEBUG J3 - Request for <244> -> <154>
2013-07-19 18:17:35,466 [17] DEBUG J3 - Request for <946> -> <1099>
```

(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,mmm is the date-time format)

I looked at the event viewer, but could find nothing out of the ordinary, no error or warning messages at all.

Is there anything that explains this behavior?

Comment: You didn't accidentally click with the mouse on the console window? That could start mark for copying, suspending all console output, and a single keypress would exit the mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't accidentally click with the mouse on the console window? That could start mark for copying, suspending all console output, and a single keypress would exit the mode.

Comment: OMG.....just tried it and that seems to be the case. Didn't pay attention to the fact that this could happen until now. I'm just shocked of how dumb I was. Thanks a lot!